# Will I preserve link equity if I use two redirects?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

I'm switching a social media site over to a Drupal platform. I'm planning to implement permanent directs (301) from each old url to the new url.

I'm using page titles in the url string on the new site:

```
http://www.newsite.com/this-is-my-page-title
```

From a technical standpoint it would be easier for me to redirect to the page id:

```
http://www.newsite.com/node/123
```

which automatically redirects (with a 301) to the above title url.

Is there a problem using two redirects or is it better to just use one?

Comment: Just FYI, [301](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) is the code for a permanent redirect. 302 is temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>No, redirects lose a little bit PageRank so each time you redirect some PR is lost. Plus multiple redirects *may* cause other crawlers to be unable to follow them through to their final destination. So, ideally you'll keep your redirects to a minimum.</s>

Apparently this has changed and the answer is, [yes, you will preserve link equity](https://moz.com/blog/301-redirection-rules-for-seo).

Comment: This is no longer the case. Gary Iles confirmed this and it is discussed here:  https://moz.com/blog/301-redirection-rules-for-seo

Comment: @John [Link Juicy and pagerank both are different thing](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102255/58259), pagerank is just the calculation of link value while other link metrics are purely based on content. You really don't need to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it too much.  Sure, in principle, the less redirects the better — but in practice, any bot or browser that can follow one redirect can certainly follow two, and [the PageRank loss from redirects is minimal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW5UL3lzBOA).  Just do whatever works for you.

(In fact, as far as I know, no-one's confirmed that there's *any* PageRank loss from redirects *within* a site.  Matt Cutts [did confirm in an interview](http://www.stonetemple.com/articles/interview-matt-cutts-012510.shtml) that 301 redirects *can* lose a small amount of PageRank, but that was in the context of cross-domain redirects.)

(Update: It has since been confirmed that, while 301 redirects may have lost some PageRank in the past, [that doesn't happen any more](https://moz.com/blog/301-redirection-rules-for-seo).  Go ahead and redirect as much as you like... within reason, that is.  A 100-step redirect chain is still a bad idea, obviously.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep the 301-redirects to a minimum.

**In summary:**

It's better to just use one 301-redirect, because:

- 301-redirects inflict some loss of link juice every time they are used (probably more than Matt Cutts would want you to believe).
- daisy-chaining 301-redirects is therefor not a good idea. Say for instance 90% of the link juice is passed on with the 301-redirect. Having another 301-redirect will in theory pass 90% x 90% = 81% of the link juice. Imagine the time you've put into linkbuilding. Preserve all the link juice you can.

**Please note** that canonical tags are mainly used as guidelines for the Search Engines. Google however usually obeys it.

Answer (score 0):

You better use `canonical` tag, **any kind of redirection** lose PageRank

Comment: thanks. If I use canonical then visitors will stay on the old site. Maybe I add a META REFRESH

Comment: I have no actual inside information to confirm this hunch, but, given that Google seems to be treating rel=canonical as more or less equivalent to a 301 redirect, I'd be pretty surprised if one of them caused any more or any less PageRank loss than the other.

Comment: @Ilmari Since Google suggest we use `canonical`, so we guess we can safely assume `canonical` won't lose more value than 301. And since there has to be some kind of jump, I believe `canonical` is a better choice. Also faster for visitors since no redirection.

Comment: Actually, it looks like [Matt Cutts has already answered this pretty definitively](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW5UL3lzBOA).